# Creating XML document from SOAP Message vs Document Builder[Source for both is Input Stream]

Tags: java, xpath, inputstream

I am basically trying to check for failures in a service by checking the response object
I have a response from a SOAP service and i expect it to be like this:
Following is the input stream

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <S:Code>
                <S:Value>S:Receiver</S:Value>
            </S:Code>
            <S:Reason>
                <S:Text xml:lang="en">org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ns2:MYREQ' is not complete. One of '{"urn:SOMETHINGELSE}' is expected.</S:Text>
            </S:Reason>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

.
When i convert this to a SOAP Message document using the below code:

```
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance("SOAP 1.2 Protocol").createMessage(null, response);
        Document responseDocument = message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();
```

The Soap enevelope is trimmed and i had only

```
<S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <S:Code>
                    <S:Value>S:Receiver</S:Value>
                </S:Code>
                <S:Reason>
                    <S:Text xml:lang="en">org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ns2:MYREQ' is not complete. One of '{"urn:SOMETHINGELSE}' is expected.</S:Text>
                </S:Reason>
            </S:Fault>
```

But when i do it this way using document builder,i get the correct output

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

                Document responseDocument = builder.parse(response);
```

Please let me know why is it that when i convert the InputStream to SOAP message and then to the document,the enevelope and the body is missing.

Comment: Well, it sounds as if `getSOAPBody()` and`extractContentAsDocument()` do what they say. If you want to see the full message then use `writeTo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();`

Here you are asking to return everything within `<S:Body>` tag of the SOAP response. If you want to get the envelope,

`SOAPPart sp = message.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope se = sp.getEnvelope();`

as mentioned in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html

Whereas in the second option instead of SOAP API you are using DOM API. This is just like converting any xml string to a `Document`. Hence the entire SOAP message is converted into simple DOM Document and you can access every node from the SOAP Response.

Comment: Thanks Shyam,How do i get the Document from Soap Envelope now?

Comment: You are already getting the `Document` by using `DocumentBuilderFactory` per your second option. Will this not suffice?

Comment: The second method is fine. I wanted to make the first one working

Comment: First one works as its intended (to get child of body). If you want to get the envelope, use the example I've provided, however you cannot get `Document` directly from it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPEnvelope.html implements Element, Node and SOAPElement interfaces. So if you get the envelope object you can perform operations defined in all those interfaces.